# Saves gallery images to phone/tablet

Tags: android, ios, image, save, gallery

I have a client that would like to have their image galleries downloadable to iphone/ipad/android that would be saved into the device as a gallery. At the moment they simply have a zip file the user downloads from their computer then has to save to their device via iTunes etc.

Does anybody know of a method to save images as a gallery to a mobile device?

There can be a separate link for each type of device.

Maybe there is an app available that the user could install that would contain the gallery? I ideally the gallery could then be updated by the client when they make changes and have those changes sync with the app (I know that is asking a bit much)

Thoughts, ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They simply can use apps like Dropbox, which have a special feature to do exactly this.

Comment: I use Dropbox very frequently and I don't really see a very user friendly way of using Dropbox to solve this. It needs to be quite straight forward for the user. If you can think of a reasonable way to use Dropbox as a solution could you please describe how?

Thanks!

Comment: Anybody else have any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: if you activate image sync in Dropbox it will sync your images to the public images folder. There you can use the built-in gallery. I am not a big fan of Dropbox, but any app would need to do the sync from the desktop to the mobile device and using the public folder will allow another app to show it nicely. In iOS this is (like many other things) of course limited.